# SQL Server table column value not update when hit by api provider

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using an API for recharge portal and provide them a page for recharge status update and the hit my page url with some query string parameter. Then I read the query string and update table. URL hit is showing in my IIS log but table is not updated but when I'm hitting manually same it has been update. I'm unable to find out reason behind.

Here is the url they hit

```
mypage.aspx?status=success&trans_no=12373&client_key=12368754&rech_no=9235155800&amount=10&opr_code=1&success_id=UEH1708181415290215&msg=recharge%20request%20was%20succeeded.
```

and here is the code of my page load event

```
string status = Request.QueryString["status"];
string apiRef = Request.QueryString["trans_no"];
string refId = Request.QueryString["client_key"];
string oRefId = Request.QueryString["success_id"];

if (status == "success")
    status = "Success";

SqlConnection conn = new 
SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString1"]);



 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE mytable SET status=@status 
 ,oreference_id= @oRefId ,udate=GETDATE() WHERE ureference_id= @refId AND 
 areference_id= @apiRef", conn);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oRefId", oRefId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refId", refId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apiRef", apiRef);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Try turning off page caching

Comment: Thanks marc_s I'm aware about that and I'll be modify my code.

Comment: Do any other SQL Statements work? I'm not sure if you can debug aspx pages but if you can I suggest you step through your code and check that the parts of the WHERE clause are what you think they are. It also helps to use SQL Profiler to observe the SQL hitting the database.

Comment: Nick when I'm hitting same copied URL from IIS log via my browser It's working perfect but I'm unable to find cause why It's not working when hit by my API provider.

Comment: Are you saying it works OK when you test, but you have a third party (API Provider??) using it and you can't recreate their issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code i hope it will work for you

```
        string status = Request.QueryString["status"];
        string apiRef = Request.QueryString["trans_no"];
        string refId = Request.QueryString["client_key"];
        string oRefId = Request.QueryString["success_id"];

        if (status == "success")
            status = "Success";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnString1"]);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE mytable SET status=@status ,oreference_id= @oRefId ,udate=GETDATE() WHERE ureference_id= @refId AND areference_id= @apiRef", conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oRefId", oRefId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refId", refId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apiRef", apiRef);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks Hafiz I'll try lets see.

Comment: Thanks Hafiz now it's working fine. But can u describe what is deference for open connection SqlCommand and after SqlCommand.What's wrong with Open SqlConnection before ExecuteNonQuery().